# How to position an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer inside a view?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I would like to display the camera preview in a square UIView. This is what I am doing :

```
previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
mySquareView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

The result is the camera preview automatically resizing to fit entirely in the view.

I want it to fit horizontally and to be cropped vertically.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`